# Error 1067 for Default of Timestamp column where there is no Default

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having trouble populating a schema in MySQL 5.5. Each table has a "create_time" and "update_time" which are Timestamps. I prefer to have no Default for these columns but I get a 1067 error referencing the Default value even when there is no Default value.

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'update_time'
```

Below is a portion of my script which is generated by MySQL Workbench.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `database` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`table` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `update_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

How can I create this table with these Timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL documentation:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table. The following notes first describe automatic initialization and updating for MySQL 5.6.5 and up, then the differences for versions preceding 5.6.5.

Since you are using 5.5 and are attempting to set both attributes with the TIMESTAMP data type, you are only guaranteed one attribute to set a default value.

This makes sense, because the `update` column is throwing the error, the second attribute to be initialized, which would not be allowed to generate a default TIMESTAMP per the docs.

Comment: To help my understanding, is there an implicit Default for Not Null fields?

Comment: There is an implicit default because they have to be initialized upon insertion, but default value that you desire from these attributes will not be returned because you are only guaranteed 1 TIMESTAMP generation per the docs.

Comment: Actually, I removed both Not Null requirements and receive the same error. I assume that even null counts as a timestamp init. I suppose I'll need to remove one of the columns.

Comment: My final solution is to use DateTime fields instead.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the table works.

But if you insert a record your need to set a value for `update_time` since `null` values are not allowed.

Otherwise an error is thrown because there is no default value that can be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Add default values to your timestamps:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`table` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Nope, sorry - "#1067 - Invalid default value for 'create_time'"

Comment: @JohnWojtk Try `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP `, see my edits. Good luck!

Comment: That opens a whole other can of worms: "#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause".

I've been working on this for a few hours :)

Comment: See @andrewdleach answer.

Comment: @JohnWojtk Try the following just for the sake of it: _\`update_time\` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00'_

Comment: Yep, same deal. "#1067 - Invalid default value for 'update_time'". I gotta say, this is pretty restricting.